# Area Between Curves - Finding intersection Point

Tags: integration, area

I wish to find the area between the curves:

$y=\sqrt{x}$

and

$y=x^{2}-3x-2$

and between $x=1, x=9$

Now, I think that the first thing to do is to find the intersection between the two curves, and then to find which curve is the upper one before and after the intersection point. At the end, an integral will follow.

The problem is, how do you find the intersection point? If you compare the curves, you get an equation which is find to solve. Is there a trick I am missing? How do you solve it when you have a square root and a power of 2?

Thank you !

Comment: $\sqrt{x}=x^2 - 3x -2$

Answer (score 1):

You ask how to solve $x^2-3x-2=\sqrt{x}$? Compute the square on both sides and you get
\begin{align}
x^2-3x-2=\sqrt{x}&\Leftrightarrow (x^2-3x-2)^2=x\\
&\Leftrightarrow x^4-6x^3+5x^2+12x+4=x\\
&\Leftrightarrow x^4-6x^3+5x^2+11x+4=0.
\end{align}
If you are lucky then you get one of $-4,-2,-1,1,2,4$ is a solution of your equation. Since you consider the positive solution, you can drop $-4$, $-2$ and $-1$. Evaluate the polynom at $1$, $2$ and $4$ and you get that $x=4$ is one solution. If you factorize you get
$$
(x-4)\underbrace{(x^3-2x^2-3x-1)}_{=:p(x)}=0.
$$
Now you have to be careful since $p(1)=1-2-3-1=-5<0$ while $p(4)=4^3-2\cdot4^2-3\cdot 4-1=19>0$. The intermediate value theorem yields a zero $\xi\in(1,4)$.

What happened? By squaring we flipped the negative part of $x^2-3x-2$ to positive and that produced a fake intersection point at $\xi$. 
But we know that $x^2-3x-2$ intersects just once $\sqrt{x}$ and since
$$
4^2-3\cdot4-2=2=\sqrt{4}
$$
we can conclude that $\xi$ is a fake solution while $4$ is the real intersection point.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a possibility of finding the area without finding the intersection? It seems weird it's so complicated.

Comment: No. You need the intersection point.

Answer (score 1):

We need to solve 
$$\sqrt{x}=x^2-3x-2.$$
We have $x\geq0$ and $x^2-3x-2\geq0$, which gives $x\geq\frac{3+\sqrt{17}}{2}$.

Thus, squaring gives
$$(x-4)(x^3-2x^2-3x-1)=0$$
and $x=4$ because for $x\geq\frac{3+\sqrt{17}}{2}$ we see that $$x^3-2x^2-3x-1=x(x^2-3x-2)+x^2-x-1=$$
$$=x(x^2-3x-2)+x^2-3x-2+2x+1>0.$$

Now, we need to calculate two integrals:
$$\int_{1}^4(\sqrt{x}-x^2+3x+2)dx+\int_{4}^9(x^2-3x-2-\sqrt{x})dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

you must solve the equation $$\sqrt{x}=x^2-3x-2$$ after squaring and factorizing you will get
$$(x-4) \left(x^3-2 x^2-3 x-1\right)=0$$ the otherone is $$x\approx 3.07959562349143878601$$

Comment: Your $x_2\approx 3.08$ is a solution of your polynomial equation but not a solution of the original equation since $\sqrt{x_2}>0>x_2^2-3x_2-2$.